# Windows store app c# - datetime converter

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-store-apps

I am using converter in windows store app in twoway mode.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
{
    return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Another approach:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
{
    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(value.ToString(),
                           "yyyy-MM-dd",
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work for me? And afkors, how to solve it?
From datePicker converter gets this string: `19.1.2014 15:43:02 +01:00` and is unable to conver.

> Error message: Converter failed to convert value of type
>   'System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' to type 'DateTime';
>   BindingExpression: Path='DateFrom'
>   DataItem='Infomed21_Mbx.Data.resultFilter, Infomed21-Mbx,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element
>   is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker' (Name='datePicker_from');
>   target property is 'Date' (type 'DateTime')

Answer (score 0):

DateTime doesn't know what to do with that string.  Try using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a explicitly set the expected string format.

Comment: `19.1.2014 15:43:02 +01:00` is definitely not of the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: if I enter dd.MM.yyyy it does not work eather. This is what i get back: 1.1.0001 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Here are my DateTime converters I use in WP8 project. They should work on W8 without any trouble

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        return date.ToShortDateString();
    }

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
        {
            return resultDateTime;
        }
        return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

Comment: my progam crashes in this line: DateTime date = (DateTime)value;